# Understanding Document.createElement()

Tags: javascript, gwt, dom

I'm using `GWT` and its underlaying `DOM` capabilities.

What I'm basically trying to achieve is :

- Have a `div` element holding some text
- Some of these text would be surrounded by `span` elements
- The span elements are draggable into each other and offers contextual menus
- New `span` elements can be created dynamically by the end-users

***This is what it could look like :***

[image: This is what it could look like]

At the startup of the application, and during end-users dynamic creation of `spans`, I have to do some `Element` and `Nodes` manipulations (creating, inserting, modifying, deleting). To achieve this, I have to go through the DOM tree to be able to find particular elements.

I'm looking for ways to reduce useless time spent at the **startup of the application**, where I build my `div` element (containing all the text and `span` elements).

Take this example :

```java
DivElement outermostDiv = Document.get().createDivElement();
processText(outermostDiv, text); // text could be a Java String element
turnTheseIntoSpans(listOfSpans, outermostDiv); // listOfSpans could be a list of text that must be surrounded by span elements.
```

Let's imagine, that `turnTheseIntoSpans` do lots of modifications of the `outermostDiv` element using methods like : `appendChild()`, `removeFromParent()`, ...

***My questions are :***

1. Is it a good practise to modify *outermostDiv* and its childs before inserting it into the DOM ?
2. I can have access to `outermostDiv` childs, sibling of childs, without having added it to the `DOM`. I would like to understand how a browsable tree of elements exists even before `outermostDiv` is added to the DOM ?

Comment: Does it have to be a span element? It would help if you explain why you cannot do it in a traditional GWT way (add widgets/elements to the panel, manipulate them as much as you need to, and then attach the panel).

Comment: @AndreiVolgin question edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Document.createDivElement()` creates an object that implements `com.google.gwt.dom.client.Node`, by calling the following JavaScript:

```js
return doc.createElement('div');
```

Such a node is not initially attached to the document tree, but even before it is, you can already perform most operations on it (except for the ones that would need its parent node, as this is still null).

Note: The node is created by the same document it will later be attached to (this is necessary, because nodes created by a different document may be incompatible - so you can't always attach all nodes everywhere).

Comment: Thank for pointing that out. I'm trying to find accurate information on what does exactly the Document when it creates a Element. Do you know where I can find any good explanation of this ?

Comment: @Jean-Michel: Basically, it just creates an object in JavaScript, which has certain members. If you want to know exactly, what these are, I would recommend playing a bit with it, e.g. in Firebug: Go to the console tab, and enter "window.mydiv = document.createElement('div');", then switch to the DOM tab, and inspect mydiv (hint: also look in `__proto__`!)

Comment: To be precise: `Document` in this sense is the global object that contains all DOM abstraction methods. It does not refer to the root of the DOM tree representing the document itself…

Comment: @Barney: It's both. The JavaScript document object is a node itself: The document node. It also contains methods to create elements etc. (but doesn't automatically attach them to the document). Of course, there's some underlying implementation (any JavaScript object is bits and bytes on an underlying level), but that's a different story. And of course, there's the abstract concept of a document, but that's yet another story :-)

Comment: Clearly my precision wasn't precise enough ;) – as you say yourself, it's not a given that a method within `Document` "doesn't automatically attach them to the document" – in pure JS DOM, the `documentElement` property of the `document` references the root of the tree – which `Document` isn't…

Comment: @Barney: This is what the DOM spec says: http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#i-Document "Conceptually, [Document] is the root of the document tree" And Document contains documentElement as the first level below that root. But your point is valid, too (because documentElement represents the `<html>` tag, which is usually at the root when looking at an HTML file), and in any case it's ok to view any node as the root of some tree :-)

Answer (score 1):

To qualify this question, I must first admit that I am a pure front-ender – I haven't played with GWT and I write raw Javascript, so this answer is based on esoteric knowledge of in-browser DOM.

1. Yes! Live document DOM manipulation is costly. Manipulating the DOM before insertion is much quicker, since things like style computations, layout reflow calculations, and DOM mutation events are run just once instead of with every individual modification.
2. It exists in the DOM – the DOM simply being the XML manipulation abstraction that was used to create it in the first place – it simply not yet part of the document DOM, and all the additional complications that brings about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a StringBuilder for your implementation. You can do all the manipulations with the StringBuilder (insert tags, change their position, etc.), and when you are done, you add its content to an HTML widget as a string. It would be much faster than creating elements, appending children, etc.

Comment: This is bad design because if I want to add a new element, I need to replace all the inner HTML. This causes many browser calculations (as stated in the others answers). Doing it with the DOM allows me to correctly set Elements attributes (such as draggable) and etc.

Comment: You can set any attributes you like within the StringBuilder. When you set its content as inner HTML, the browser will rerender the page - once (the same as when you attach your outmost element to DOM). After that you have your elements in DOM that you can drag, replace, whatever. The difference in our approaches is what happens before you touch the DOM, and building a string is more efficient than creating each element individually, attaching them to each other in the right order, and then attaching the whole thing to DOM.

Comment: How do you set for example the `draggable` attribute of your inserted spans ? How do you manage to dynamically add a new span at some point of the DOM tree ?

Comment: sb.append("<span id=\" + spanId + "\" draggabble=\"true\" class=\"selected\">" + spanContent + "</span>");   This is just an example. You can set id to each child and access them directly by id, or you can remember the outmost element and iterate through its children after it was added to the DOM.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Thanks for sharing. I've run some tests, and innerHTML's speed is comparable to inserting a span element with plenty of children.